# Assigned value in asynctask Shows null in other function

Tags: android

i have assigned string value in asynctask from json, but it shows null value in onclick function. here is my declaration of string variable

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    String due,total;
```

here is my assigned string value `total` in asynctask from json

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

                    for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        total = jo.getString("due");
```

in this class `total`value assigned as "name1" and also shown in println result in logcat. but when i assign this value to other string varible in onclicklistener function its println result shows null

this is my full activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner sname;
    private EditText txtamount;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> sdap;
    String amount,mem,due,total;
    TableLayout tableLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.tblLoan);
        sname = findViewById(R.id.spnMem);
        sname.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        txtamount = findViewById(R.id.txtLonCr);
        Getdata getdata = new Getdata();
        getdata.execute();
        sdap = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
        sdap.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sname.setAdapter(sdap);
    }



    protected class Getdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        private String jsonurl;
        private  String str;

        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute()
        {

            jsonurl="http://10.0.2.2/dwnloandata.php";

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                tableLayout.removeAllViews();
                URL url = new URL(jsonurl);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
                {
                    json.append(line).append('\n');
                    str=json.toString();

                }


                if (str != null){

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONArray name = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

                    for (int i=0; i< name.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jo= name.getJSONObject(i);
                        names.add(jo.getString("name"));
                        TableRow raw = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                        raw.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        raw.setId(i+1);
                        TextView nm = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        nm.setWidth(650);
                        nm.setHeight(250);
                        nm.setTextSize(20);
                        nm.setText(jo.getString("name"));
                        TextView amnt = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        amnt.setTextSize(20);
                        amnt.setWidth(600);
                        amnt.setHeight(250);
                        amnt.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        amnt.setText(jo.getString("due"));
                        tableLayout.addView(raw);
                        raw.addView(nm);
                        raw.addView(amnt);
                    }}



                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            sdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        mem=item;

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    private class MembersLoan extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        private String jsonurl,str;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            jsonurl = "http://10.0.2.2/dwnsingleloandata.php";
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String member = strings[0];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(jsonurl);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(member,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String line;
                StringBuilder jaon = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    jaon.append(line).append("\n");
                    str = jaon.toString();
                }

                if( str != null)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

                    for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        total = jo.getString("due");
                        System.out.println("due==" + total);
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        amount = txtamount.getText().toString();
        due = total;
        LoanCreditInsert loanCreditInsert = new LoanCreditInsert(view.getContext());
        loanCreditInsert.execute(mem,amount);
        MembersLoan membersLoan = new MembersLoan();
        membersLoan.execute(mem);
        System.out.println("Amount=" + amount);
        System.out.println("due=" + due);
        int bdue = Integer.valueOf(due);
        int ade = Integer.valueOf(amount);

        int ldue = bdue - ade;
        String ldu = String.valueOf(ldue);

        LoanInsert loanInsert = new LoanInsert(view.getContext());
        loanInsert.execute(mem,amount,ldu);

        Getdata getdata = new Getdata();
        getdata.execute();

    }
}
```

Comment: This is absolutelly not enough info for understanding the problem. Please, post the whole Activity and that AsyncTask too, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> membersLoan.execute(mem);

You cannot have code (that uses the result of doInBackground()) after such a call.

Put all following code in the onPostExecute of MenbersLoan.

In general: If you start an asynctask with .execute() then you cannot have more code after the call. If you have 'following code' then put that code in the onPostExecute() of that task.

As you have about four/five asynctasks you can only call the next one in onPostExecute of the former.

There is work to do... just a little bit editing.

Comment: thanks, you mean i should call second asynctask in onpostexecute of first asynctask right?

Comment: Yes. Indeed. Thats what you should do. And fourth asynctask in onPostExecute of third task. And no code after an .execute().

Comment: thank i works, but when i call loaninsert in postexecute of loancreditinsert ,variable mem goes blank whereas 'mem' value as it is inserted in loancredit and also want to update this table layout with new row by inserted data in loan database

Comment: I solved 'mem' variable problem, but I still can't solve table update

Answer (score 0):

```
LoanCreditInsert loanCreditInsert = new LoanCreditInsert(view.getContext());
        loanCreditInsert.execute(mem,amount);
        MembersLoan membersLoan = new MembersLoan();
        membersLoan.execute(mem);
```

Please execute one by one asynctask and try.